# Use Git locally at work in conjunction with custom "source control"

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

At work, we are required to use a custom "source control" system. Basically, it takes snapshots of our code whenever we push new changes to our live environment. There are no rollback capabilities except to get a copy of the last live push, there are no mechanisms for seeing who changed what, and once one person is working on the code someone else can change the source and you would not know (unless you spotted the change).

I would like to implement Git in this environment but I'm not wise enough in the ways of Git to figure out how best to do this. Here are the requirements that I need to handle:

- Source code is stored on a remote file path.
- Once I start a project, anyone can change the remote source (I would like to capture these changes if possible).
- The source is (usually) existing before I start to work on it.
- After I complete a project, someone else may change the source (not using Git).
- I am going to attempt to get the rest of my coworkers involved in doing this too.
- I have only file read/write access to the remote server.
- My coworkers do not like the command prompt (and, quite frankly, I prefer to use a GUI), so use of a GUI (like GitHub for Windows or, even better, the Team Explorer tools inside Visual Studio) would be a high priority.
- We are a Windows-only shop specializing in C# and ASP.NET MVC so any solutions would need to work inside those bounds.
- The impact on the remote files and folders should be minimal. I know Git is light but anything I can do to keep it as invisible as possible will be great.

I've looked into how to do this but I've not found a good solution that works for me (or at least that I understand would work for me). I found this article but it didn't appear to really work well for my environment (again, maybe that is my lack of understanding):
http://mattsnider.com/develop-locally-using-git-instead-of-your-company-s-crappy-version-control/

Any help that you can give would be much appreciated. I would really appreciate it if the help you give is doable for a Git user (me) who is not very knowledgeable. Steps to follow and instructions on why would be tremendous.

Comment: with all the real source control systems both paid and free that are out there, if your employer doesn't care to use one, do yourself a favor and bolt!

Comment: @Jason Yes, run away from your problems rather than try to fix them. That definitely the best thing to do...

Comment: @Chibbles if his/her employer was willing to use one, I'm sure the op would have suggested and gotten them to use one.  I fail to see how that is "running away from your problems", if your employer one day told you to start writing your code on pen and paper and submit to a professional typist who types 1,000 times faster than you and won't budge to giving you an IDE, you think it really makes sense to stick around?  Have fun and enjoy yourself then...although on a second thought...you are the op's employer, aren't you!?   :P

Comment: [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) is a great git GUI (that costs money); [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is another GUI (that is available for free). See [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#Graphical_Interfaces) for a full list.

Comment: No, @Chibbles isn't my employer. :-) As for bolting, I'm instead trying to show how Git would be beneficial in the current environment. Once I do that, I think I can get a slow shift over to a "real" source control system. I'm trying to fix the situation instead of leaving it for someone else to clean up. And yes, I have suggested changing over and I have demoed Git and other source control systems. So far, I get interest but no permission to move forward.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger - Thanks for the list of tools, but this is the minor part of my question. Important, but not the true issue. The true issue is how to configure Git to work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

If your employer already has an established version control system that can handle all their different artefacts that the company needs to store (which will be more than just source code) then don't even try to actually change *their* system.

The question is more about how you can help yourself, which will depend on the level of access you have to personal storage and to network storage - the latter being maintained by others.

Assuming you have local storage, then you can set up a git repository within your own local copy of the source code. You would then set up a remote on a/your network drive to act as your back-up. (as described in the blog you reference).

I use (variously) Git-for-Windows, Git-Gui, gitk, and Git Extensions for my development so that I can pick and mix the best tool/command for any particular task. I find it especially useful for my Matlab development with its rapid interactive edit-fix-update common in (my sort of) systems engineering.

When I have a stable version in a commit, that I want to send back to the company VCS, I can then check it out/back-in (or whatever their process demands) to their system (do tag that commit).

Likewise if there is an update to another file that you need from their VCS you should have a branch for receiving it's checkout, followed by a merge back into your development branch (or whatever flow most suits you).

Regularly push your local repo onto your bare network repo so you have a backup and some security. You can always bundle your repo, or archive a commit as required for other backups if you need.